# Multi-field search in the elasticsearch-js library

Tags: javascript, node.js, search, elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch (managed instance from [searchly](https://www.searchly.com)) with the [elasticsearch-js](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js/) npm client library. I want to search multiple fields in my index from a term. There seems to be loads of [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/multi-query-strings.html) on this, e.g.

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        { "match": { "title":  "War and Peace" }},
        { "match": { "author": "Leo Tolstoy"   }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

where I could just set the same value for author and title. However, this is a get request and is structured differently to the nodejs library, where I am doing this:

```
this._client.search({
  index: 'sample',
  body: {
    query: {
      match: {
        name: 'toFind'
      }
    }
  }
}).then(function (resp) {
  var hits = resp.hits.hits;
}, function (err) {
  console.trace(err.message);
});
```

I can't have multiple `match:` fields otherwise tsc complains about strict mode, and if I try something like:

```
    query: {
      match: {
        name: 'toFind',
        description: 'toFind'
      }
    }
```

then I get an error:

> "type": "query_parsing_exception",
>
> "reason": "[match] query parsed in simplified form, with direct field name, but included more options than just the field name, possibly use its \u0027options\u0027 form, with \u0027query\u0027 element?",

Answer (score 8):

Since you want to match same string on multiple fields you need [multi match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) query. Try something like this

```
this._client.search({
  index: 'sample',
  body: {
    query: {
      multi_match: {
        query: 'toFind',
        fields: ['name','description']
      }
    }
  }
}).then(function (resp) {
  var hits = resp.hits.hits;
}, function (err) {
  console.trace(err.message);
});
```

Comment: how do you add weights to the fields?